# Loop through collection with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, collections

For the simplicity of the question, the model i'm sending to the view contains a property which is of type `ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }`.

In my view it's hidden like so:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Persons)
```

Once an `ActionLink` is pressed, first and last name of the person will be added to a (kendo) grid.

```
$('#add').click(function (personObject)
    {
        var personId= $("#PersonId").val();
        alert(personId);


        return false;
    });
```

Some more info: The person gets selected from a dropdownlist. Behind this DDL is the `ActionLink`, which has a `HtmlAttribute`pointing to the `JQuery` function it needs to call.

That all works fine.

What i'm trying to accomplish here, is to look up the first and last name of the person that got selected from the dropdownlist.

Based on the Id of that person, i need to get the first and last name out of the hidden "Persons" collection property:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Persons)
```

How can I do this using `JQuery`?

Comment: Showing the HTML would clear things up. What's the generated code?

Comment: it would be better if your HTML element was holding JSON for the object, then you can iterate over the object using jQuery.

Comment: @abc123, do you mean instead of ICollection, JSON? How can I do that?

Comment: @Broxzier, unfortunately, i can't post that. I'll have to mask too much. But if you tell me what exactly you are interested in seeing what is outputted as HTML, i'll look into it. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Yustme I understand. Useful information (for me at least) would be the dropdown list (Is this `#PersonId`?) and if not, what element is `#PersonId`.

Comment: @Broxzier, yes that's the dropdownlist. Martin Ernst got me into the right direction. Its fixed. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to serialize your collection into a format that you can read in javascript.

For example:

```
@Html.Hidden("Persons", Json.Encode(Model.Persons))
```

Then you can parse this data using something like:

```
<script> 
    var persons = JSON.parse($("#Persons").val());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HiddenFor won't work with collections, only single values. Why not get the names from the model or do a call to the server.

Comment: Hi, i know, but it was for the simplicity of the question. Too much to explain. sorry.